# Load SetupIconFile icon from an exe file

Tags: file, icons, installation, inno-setup

Is there any way to load the setup icon from an exe?
The below line **doesn't** work:

```
[Setup]
SetupIconFile: "{#MyAppExeName}, {#MyIconIndex}"
```

Thanks.

Comment: You did a similar mistake as in your previous question. Do not enclose a binary file name with an icon index in quotes. They should have been separated. But, in this case you're out of luck. For the `SetupIconFile` directive you can specify only an *.ico file.

Comment: @SirRufo This is not a duplicate as that asks about setting a shortcut icon. This is asking about one compiled into the setup itself. Please remove your close request.